# How to disable Authentication Required popup after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: 22.04

This shows up every time I reboot and launch any application. I am already logged in as an admin user. If I entered a password to unlock, it goes away until the next reboot. How can I disable this popup persistently?

Ubuntu: 22.04

[image]

Comment: Auto-login does not unlock some parts of the keyring and some other passwords that require authentication. It's a little inconvenience for the convenience of auto-login.

Comment: So, disable auto-login (as you shouldn't use it at all) and it won't happen.

Comment: Thank you, it's already disabled. Do I need to reset the keyring or something?

Comment: What or who is the Admin user Ubuntu has no such user.

Comment: My user is in sudoers. But the point is regardless of the the check, it keeps asking every reboot. Has the keyring file got corrupted or something? This never happened before upgrade.

Comment: Does the password for the keyring match the login password?  You might have to reset the password to the keyring after you have typed in that password.  You can get to the keyring by running Alt+F2 then run `seahorse` or you can run it from a terminal window.  If the system is not shared you can not set a password and blank it out and that will work too.  I am not in front of my system to test it out, but I am thinking that if the passwords match and it still does this then it is a bug that was never fixed.

Comment: If 1) you are not using auto login, and 2) the only keyring you have is the login keyring you simply need to change the keyring password to make it match the login password.  If you have another keyring labeled default or whatever, you can either move the stuff from it into the login keyring or have the login keyring unlock the default one.